# Modify identityserver4 authorize

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, blazor

I'm using IdentityServer4 and EF Core in my Blazor WASM project with ASP.NET Core hosted option and in that project I use multiple databases.(dynamic string connection - duplicates of databases)
In the login page you choose what database to use and I store the database name in the cookies.
The system should work like that when you login using one database you can't use the other databases.
Every thing is working fine except that that I can change the database name in the cookies and then use the other databases.
My question is how can I modify the IdentityServer4 authroize so when you login using one database you can't access the another databases(return 403 error code when send http request if you changed database name in cookies) - database depended. 

I thought maybe I could check each request if token is stored in AspNetUserTokens table ,but I noticed that the table is empty even after logged in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the current database value should be set as a Claim on the user's identity, rather than in a raw cookie. Adding custom claims to the identity will protect them in an encrypted token.

Here's [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#name-and-role-claim-with-api-authorization) around this scenario, in particular look at implementing an IProfileService that adds your claim.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't working so what I did is to add a new column to the AspNetUsers table and store that the database identifier